# Display selected values from a dropdown list along with other form values on another page in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display entered form values including whatever option was chosen in a dropdown list on another page. If the code for displaying the dropdown list on the next page is not removed then the next page simply doesn't show any of the submitted form values. But if that code is removed then all of the form values are displayed.

I simply cannot workout where I am going wrong here in terms of displaying the selected dropdown list value along with whatever else was submitted in the form.

Part of the form where the dropdown list is

```
<label for="product_interests"><b>Product interests</b></label>
     <select type="text" placeholder="Enter product interests" name="product_interests" id="product_interests" required>
     <br></br>
        <option value="undecided">Undecided</option>
        <option value="french_toast_and_bacon">French toast and bacon</option>
        <option value="lamingtons">Lamingtons</option>
        <option value="home_styles_soup_of_the_day">Home styles soup of the day</option>
        <option value="cheeseburger">Cheeseburger</option>
        <option value="sun_and_moon_sandwich">Sun and moon sandwich</option>
        <option value="bacon_turnovers">Bacon turnovers</option>
        <option value="fettucine_alfredo_pasta">Fettucine alfredo pasta</option>
        <option value="crispy_skinned_barramundi">crispy skinned barramundi</option>
        <option value="lamb_cuttlets">Lamb cuttlets</option>
    </select>
     <label>
       <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
     </label>

     <p>By subscribing to our newsletter you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

     <div class="clearfix">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
     </div>
   </div>
```

Function that saves the entered values

```
function submitForm(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        localStorage.fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        localStorage.lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        localStorage.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        localStorage.birthday = document.getElementById("birthday").value;
        localStorage.product_interests = document.getElementById("product_interests").option;
    }
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Where the values on the next page are supposed to be displayed

```
<div id="fname">
</div>
<div id="lname">
</div>
<div id="email">
</div>
<div id="birthday">
</div>
<div id="product_interests">
</div>
</body>
```

function that displays the values on the next page

```
 function setData(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML = "First name: " + localStorage.fname;
        document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML = "Last name: " + localStorage.lname;
        document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "Email: " + localStorage.email;
        document.getElementById("birthday").innerHTML = "Birthday: " + localStorage.birthday;
        document.getElementById("product_interests"). = "Product interests: " + localStorage.product_interests;
    
    /*if(typeof(localStorage) == "undefined"){
    document.getElementById("product_interests").innerHTML = "Product interests: " + localStorage.product_interests;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: There is no point in duplicating submit. You are already doing it here - `document.getElementById("form").submit();`.

Comment: That didn’t change anything.